# Javascript: Add cols / rows to 2d matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, matrix, col

I have an array (2d matrix) like this:

```
var matrix = [
      '0000',   
      '1100',     
      '1100'  
    ]
```

... And I'd like to add rows and cols at a specific positions. 
See in the examples below - **Adding col at index (x) 0** & **adding row at index (y) 0**.

```
var matrix = [                    var result = [
  '0000',                          '00000',
  '1100',         add col -->      '01100',
  '1100'                           '01100'
]                                 ]
```

and ...

```
var matrix = [                    var result = [
   '0000',                          '0000',
   '1100',                          '0000',
   '1100'         add row -->       '1100',
                                    '1100'
]                                 ]
```

Is there some better/elegant way to get this result instead of using a stupid for loop? (col example below)

```js
var matrix = [
    '0000',
    '1100',
    '1100',
]


function add_col(matrix, x) {
    for (var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
        matrix[i] = matrix[i].slice(0, x) + "0" + matrix[i].slice(x);
    }
    return matrix.join('\n')
}
console.log(add_col(matrix, 0))
```

Comment: IMO the stupid `for` loop is going to be the most performant among the options. So the elegant way would be to just wrap it in a function.

Comment: You can use `Array#map` or `Array#forEach`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving programming style are more on-topic for CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Using map might look more elegant, but it isn't faster: `matrix.map(row => row.slice(0, x) + "0" + row.slice(x));` - I'd use arrays of numbers instead of strings if you want to update your matrices often.

Answer (score -2):

Yes can possible with map function

```
var matrix = [
    '0000',
    '1100',
    '1100',
]

result=matrix.map(function(x) { return "0"+x});
```

Comment: Here "0" is added as first row as so in a result